# Fix it: convergence of $\{a_n\}$ given that $b_n = a_n + 1/a_n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

Spinoff of: [Convergence of $\{a_n\}$ given that $b_n = a_n + 1/a_n$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/981687/convergence-of-a-n-given-that-b-n-a-n-1-a-n-converges)

$$b_n = a_n + \frac{1}{a_n}$$

I recently read this guy's post and his proof of part (a) of the question. However, I believe there are some problems. We have that 
$$|b_{n_i} - b_{n_j}| = |a_{n_i} - a_{n_j} + 1/a_{n_i} - 1/a_{n_j}| < \epsilon$$
but then we know that $a_{n_i} - a_{n_j}>0 \implies 1/a_{n_i} - 1/a_{n_j}<0$ so in fact using this inequality we can not reach any conclusions about $|a_{n_i} - a_{n_j}|$ because $|a_{n_i} - a_{n_j} + 1/a_{n_i} - 1/a_{n_j}| < a_{n_i} - a_{n_j}$, when we want the other direction of inequality. It seems to me that this approach is flawed. How can we prove that the $a_n$ converge if not from this approach?

Comment: In fact, if you neglect the hypothesis that $a_n\geqslant1,\forall n$, you can construct a sequence like the answer from Mr. Mostafa Ayaz in the original post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that part (a), there's the important hypothesis that $a_n \geq 1$ for all $n$.

Then it is a matter of solving quadratic equations.

Since $b_n = a_n + 1/a_n \geq 2$, we can solve $a_n$ from $b_n$:
$$a_n = \frac{b_n + \sqrt{b_n^2 - 4}}{2}.$$
The plus sign is because of the hypothesis $a_n\geq 1$.

Is it then clear?

Comment: so it converges because we can pull the limits next to the b_n which do have a limit? I thought the solution would be prettier. :(

Comment: Well... at least it works for this particular problem (:

Comment: but it's legal to move in limits and stuff? And $a_n\geq 1$ was important to make sure the discriminant is positive?

Comment: It's legal because all involved functions are continuous. And $a_n\geq 1$ was important to assure that we don't get the other root $a_n = \frac{b_n - \sqrt{b_n^2 - 4}}{2}$.